# How to use Auditing in JPA/Spring-Data JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, auditing, spring-data

I am using JPA & Spring-Data JPA in a project. I have one table wherei Insert and then update the data. However i need the auditing information to save the state of all the objects i.e. I need state information of insert and all subsequent updates in another Table. I know I can use triggers in database to do this. However, Can this be done using JPA/Spring Data JPA?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JPA spec ([section 3.5](http://download.oracle.com/auth/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf?e=1308828683&h=5ab36efb83333c7df78d4fac2f0aea8b)) defines lifecycle callback methods:

- prePersist
- postPersist
- preRemove
- postRemove
- preUpdate
- postUpdate
- postLoad

which are probably the closest thing you will find in pure JPA.  SpringData itself has further auditing capabilities which are at a slightly higher level of abstraction.  It describes these in section 2.4 of the [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.auditing).

Comment: Although the JPA spec will allow you to do this, Spring Data Jpa has a very slick mechanism built in to do just this: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.auditing

Answer (score 1):

See,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Auditing_and_Security

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#History

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Auditing

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History

Comment: I saw the above links and they specify the History Feature can be used in JPA but i saw links of only TOPLINK and ECLIPSELINK. Any idea if it can be used with Hibernate also?