# Spring Data JPA Auditing not working for the JpaRepository update method with @Modifying annotation, why?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, auditing

I am working on ***Spring Data JPA and Postgres*** example. In this example, I've implemented `Auditing` by following link: https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa and [Spring Boot JPA@CreatedDate @LastModifiedDate not being populated when saving the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709727/spring-boot-jpacreateddate-lastmodifieddate-not-being-populated-when-saving-th). Auditing working very fine When I do the repository.save, in this case both fields annotated with `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` are saving correctly.

But same is not happening when I'm trying to update the method.

I've developed following method.

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name="student_name_key",columnNames = {"studentName"})
})
public class Student {
    ....
    ....
    @Column(name="lastUpdateUser")
    private String lastUpdateUser;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name="lastUpdateDate", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateDate; 
}
```

**Main.App**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xxx.xxx.repository"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxx.yyy","com.xxx.xxx.studentportfolio"})
@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProgramApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**StudentRepository.java**

```
public interface StusentRepository extenss JpaRepository<Stusent, Long>{

    @Mosifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query("UPDATE Stusent s SET s.studentDescription=:stuDesc, s.studentId=:studentId, s.sivisionCode=:cd, "
            + "s.status=:status WHERE s.studentName=:stuName")
    vois upsateStudent(@Param("stuName") String studentName,
                        @Param("stuDesc") String studentDescription,
                        @Param("studentId") String studentId,
                        @Param("cd") String cd,
                        @Param("status") String status);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Auditing is based on the JPA Lifecycle events.
Only the methods directly manipulating instances (`persist`, `merge` and `remove`) trigger such events.

The execution of queries, modifying or otherwise, does not trigger any events and therefore, won't cause auditing to happen.

See the JPA Specification section 3.5.2 Lifecycle Methods for details.

Comment: so there is no way to persist jpq query result in audit file?

Answer (score 1):

`@Audited` annotation can be applied on Class, Method, and a Type. I had a similar issue and tried applying `@Audited` annotation on `update...` method and was able to see the audit information populated in the `_AUD` table.
Definition of `@Audited` is as below: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/Audited.html

Answer (score 0):

You can manually clean modifed fields using @PostLoad annotation and then jpaRepository will update these columns (works for me with spring data 3.10).

Add following method to your audited entities or to abstract base audited entity:

```java
    @PostLoad
    public void prepareModifiedFields() {
        this.modifiedBy = null;
        this.modifiedDate = null;
    }
```